# How do you use Sass with Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: ruby, sass, aptana

I'm trying to get into using Sass but I have to say that my mind is a little boggled.

I've installed ruby and compass through the command prompt.

In aptana in the www folder I have a 'projects' folder and then subfolders for each project.

How do I go about using Sass with aptana for my projects?

Comment: Did you ask google first?  http://andrewpwatson.com/posts/how-set-compass-sass-windows-aptana-studio-3

Comment: Yes I did. I followed that post up to "compass create C:\Clientwork\APW\apw.misc --sass-dir=sass --css-dir=css" where it lost me.

Comment: Did you run that command in your console (same as all the other commands in the tutorial)?

Comment: the directory path is an example of his own project. I don't even know what a .misc file is. Nor do I recognize his path. Is clientwork his project folder? And if so what is APW? I need to know how to set it up in relation to my projects being in "www/projects/project_name."

Comment: It's just a Compass command (see: http://compass-style.org/install/).  Try running it and see what happens.  If it doesn't put the files where they're supposed to be, delete them and try again.

Comment: But do I want the files installed into my individual projects? Into their CSS folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am Giving Detailed Description for setting up sass with compass in Aptana studio for Newbies too.

First of Download Ruby in your system Get it From http://rubyinstaller.org/ and install it.

Open Up Aptana studio.

- Go to **Windows >> show view >> Terminal**
- In Terminal type `gem update --system`
- `gem install compass`

OK, now go to project explorer make a new project (or existing) *ex: myproject*

click on myproject folder and type in terminal of Aptana studio **compass create**

It will make some files in your folder something like this:

[image: Sass file structure]

Type `compass watch` in terminal

Now whenever you type in scss files **it will automatically save in stylesheets/screen.css** or in print.css orie.css

From 2-3 Commands your with super power in CSS, Have Fun !!